# Python-Pygame Level Select Pages

Tags: python, pygame, multi-level, levels

I'm trying to create a typing game. You know that point in many apps,where there is a level select, and there are several pages. Yeah, I'm trying to do that. Every time I select the button to move to the next page of level selections, it heads to the last page, and then starts to do some sort of recursion. Help! Here is the code, feel free to paste it in to your computer, and see whats wrong. (I am aware that it's messy right now the main problem is within the section that will be within the lines) Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (175,0,0)
green = (34,177,76)
yellow = (175,175,0)
blue = (30,144,255)
light_green = (0,255,0)
light_red = (255,0,0)
light_yellow = (255,255,0)
light_blue = (0,191,255)

smallFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comicsansms", 20)
medFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comicsansms", 45)
largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comicsansms", 55)



gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Typing Game")


def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurf = smallFont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurf = medFont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurf = largeFont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurf, textSurf.get_rect()


def messageToScreen(msg, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurface, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (display_width/2), (display_height/2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurface, textRect)

def text_to_button(msg, color, buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, size = "small"):
    textSurface, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = ((buttonX + (buttonWidth/2), buttonY + (buttonHeight/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurface, textRect)

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactiveColor , activeColor,textColor = black, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+ width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeColor, (x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if action == "directions":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                directions()
            if action == "lvl":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                levelScreen()
            if action == "clear":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                clearData()
            if action == "main":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                startScreen()
            if action == "page2":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                page2()
            if action == "page3":
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                pygame.display.update()
                page3()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactiveColor, (x,y,width,height))

    text_to_button(text,textColor,x,y,width,height)

def clearData():
    pass

def levelScreen():
    level = True

    while level:
        global levelnumber
        levelnumber = 1 
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        messageToScreen("Level Select", green, -200, size = "large")
        button("Back",150, 500,150,50, light_yellow, yellow, action = "main")
        button("Quit",350,500,150,50,light_red,red,action = "quit")
        button("Next",550,500,150,50,light_yellow,yellow,action = "page2")
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                level = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

def page2():
    level = True
    print("page2")
    while level:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        messageToScreen("Level Select", green, -200, size = "large")
        button("Previous",150, 500,150,50, light_yellow, yellow, action = "lvl")
        button("Quit",350,500,150,50,light_red,red,action = "quit")
        button("Next",550,500,150,50,light_yellow,yellow,action = "page3")
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                level = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

def page3():
    level = True
    print("page3")

    while level: 
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        messageToScreen("Level Select 2", green, -200, size = "large")
        button("Previous",150, 500,150,50, light_yellow, yellow, action = "lvl")
        button("Quit",350,500,150,50,light_red,red,action = "quit")
        button("Next",550,500,150,50,light_yellow,yellow,action = "main")
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                level = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

def directions():
    directions = True

    while directions:

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        messageToScreen("Directions", green, -200, size = "large")
        messageToScreen("Click The Buttons To Navigate",black,-100)
        messageToScreen("Select Level Buttons To Start The Level",black,-60)
        messageToScreen("Complete A Level By Typing All The Words In The Level",black,-20)
        messageToScreen("Each Level Is Timed And Gets Harder And Harder",black,20)
        messageToScreen("Have Fun!!!",blue,80, size = "medium")
        button("Back",150, 500,150,50, light_yellow, yellow, action = "main")
        button("Quit",550,500,150,50,light_red,red,action = "quit")
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                directions = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



def startScreen():

    game = True
    while game:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)


        messageToScreen("Welcome To The Typing Game", green, -100, size = "large")
        button("Lvl Select",150, 300,150,50, light_green, green, action = "lvl")
        button("Directions",350, 300,150,50, light_yellow, yellow, action = "directions")
        button("Quit Game",550, 300,150,50, light_red, red, action = "quit")
        button("Clear Data", 350, 400,150,50, light_blue, blue, action = "clear")


        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
startScreen()
```

Comment: You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As I said before, I think the problem is within the marked area, i cant just post that thing, because everything I wrote is connected. I did my best at showing where I think my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue that is going around. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31718675/5168325). Is the button code your own? It might be good for someone to let the original code owner know about these questions so they can change their code or show some other usage examples.

On your level select screen you are drawing a next button. When I click that button it is generating a click event and Pygame starts to draw the next screen.

The new screen has a next button in the exact same position. There is code in the button creation that checks if a button is being clicked. I am talking about these 2 lines in the button function:

```
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
...
    if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
```

Since that is being checked while the button is being created it assumes that you have clicked the new button and it goes to the next screen.

That is the answer to the question to that you asked. Here are my suggestions for the next step:

- Move the checking of a button being clicked to the main loop and not in the button creation code. The main loop of your code starts on 180
- Add some code (like I suggested in the answer of the link provided) that will make sure a user releases their click before that code fires.

I hope this helps.